# Installshield OnInstalledXXX called magically?

Tags: installshield

I am a newbie when it comes to InstallShield. I have a Setup.RUL that I am guessing is driving the entire installation process. However, there is a function called OnInstalledXXX() (XXX is a randomly chosen name) that is called at the end of the installation. However, I cannot find the caller anywhere in the RUL. When I debug it and put a break in the function, it gets hit. But if I change the name of the function from OnInstalledXXX() to OnInstalledYYY(), then it won't be called.

Does anyone know how this thing works and where is the caller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be marked as a Feature Event. Those are linked by name, so changing the name of the function would break it like you describe. You can either search in the Direct Editor for the function's name, or you can visit each of your project's features to find it. (Of course the latter will only work if I guessed correctly.)